# C++ how to pass vector of objects by reference into a function, then into next function?

Tags: c++

I'm hoping somebody can provide some assistance here.  Here is the relevant portion of the code I'm stuck on currently:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void matchBlobs(std::vector<Blob> &existingBlobs, std::vector<Blob> &currentFrameBlobs) {

    for (auto &existingBlob : existingBlobs) {
        existingBlob.blnCurrentMatchFoundOrNewBlob = false;
    }

    for (auto &currentFrameBlob : currentFrameBlobs) {

        int intIndexOfLeastDistance = 0;
        double dblLeastDistance = 1000000.0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < existingBlobs.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (existingBlobs[i].blnStillBeingTracked == true) {
                double dblDistance = distanceBetweenBlobs(currentFrameBlob, existingBlobs[i]);

                if (dblDistance < dblLeastDistance) {
                    dblLeastDistance = dblDistance;
                    intIndexOfLeastDistance = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (dblLeastDistance < currentFrameBlob.dblDiagonalSize * 1.5) {
            addBlobToExistingBlobs(currentFrameBlob, existingBlobs, intIndexOfLeastDistance); // !!!! compiler error for 2nd arg on this line !!!!!!!
        } else {
            addNewBlob(currentFrameBlob, existingBlobs);
        }

    }

    for (auto &existingBlob : existingBlobs) {
        if (existingBlob.blnCurrentMatchFoundOrNewBlob == false) {
            existingBlob.blnStillBeingTracked = false;
        }

    }

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void addBlobToExistingBlobs(Blob &currentFrameBlob, std::vector<Blob> &existingBlobs, int &intIndex) {

    existingBlobs[intIndex].contour = currentFrameBlob.contour;
    existingBlobs[intIndex].boundingRect = currentFrameBlob.boundingRect;
    existingBlobs[intIndex].ptCurrentCenter = currentFrameBlob.ptCurrentCenter;
    existingBlobs[intIndex].dblDiagonalSize = currentFrameBlob.dblDiagonalSize;
    existingBlobs[intIndex].dblAspectRatio = currentFrameBlob.dblAspectRatio;

    existingBlobs[intIndex].vectorOfAllActualPoints.push_back(currentFrameBlob.ptCurrentCenter);

    existingBlobs[intIndex].blnStillBeingTracked = true;
    existingBlobs[intIndex].blnCurrentMatchFoundOrNewBlob = true;
}
```

As noted on the comment in the code, I'm getting a compiler error on this line:

```
addBlobToExistingBlobs(currentFrameBlob, existingBlobs, intIndexOfLeastDistance); // !!!! compiler error for 2nd arg on this line !!!!!!!
```

the error is:

```
Error C2664 'void addBlobToExistingBlobs(Blob &,Blob &,int &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::vector<Blob,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'Blob &'  ObjectTrackingCPP   c:\users\cdahms\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\objecttrackingcpp2\objecttrackingcpp.cpp  186
```

Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here?  I can find plenty of C++ examples of passing one basic data type variable (int, double, etc.) by reference but I am unable to find any examples involving passing a vector of objects into one function, then into another function.

I'm using the compiler that ships with Visual Studio 2015 Community, with the default options chosen if that makes a difference.

I'm not sure what direction to go here, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the declaration of `addBlobToExistingBlobs`. The compiler believes that it takes a single `Blob` as its second parameter, not a vector of `Blob`s you are trying to pass. My guess would be, you've declared it differently in the header than you did in the code you've shown.

Comment: Good call, you're dead on, dumb mistake on my part.  I changed the function prototypes to match the code above and it compiled no problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: A bit of `const` here and there would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears - from the error message - that the compiler knows your function as

```
void addBlobToExistingBlobs(Blob&, Blob&, int&);
```

whereas, in your implementation of

```
void matchBlobs(std::vector<Blob>&, std::vector<Blob>&);
```

a function with the name of `addBlobToExistingBlobs` is used, but with a different prototype, namely

```
void addBlobToExistingBlobs(Blob& ,std::vector<Blob>&, int&);
```

Have you checked that, somewhere in your code, you haven't a prototype for another `addBlobToExistingBlobs` function that gets the compiler confused ?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured that you found your solution in earlier comments... my mistake !

Comment: Thanks anyway, as you indicated I updated the function prototypes and the code ran great, thanks again.